# How to display og:image given a page's url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

I have a site for shopping recommendations, which allows users to post the urls for items they recommend.

The form currently includes just a single input for a url to the main product page.

If a user were to post a link like below:

http://www.homedepot.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/ProductDisplay?productId=203533553&storeId=10051&langId=-1&catalogId=10053&cm_sp=BlackFriday-_-11_23-_-Hero_C-_-349_Each_GE_Washer_Dryer_Special_Buy#.UK-DHuOe_VQ

I would want to show an image tag of the og:image included in this url.

Using the facebook open graph protocol page, I see that the example url above does indeed have an og:image

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.homedepot.com%2Fwebapp%2Fwcs%2Fstores%2Fservlet%2FProductDisplay%3FproductId%3D203533553%26storeId%3D10051%26langId%3D-1%26catalogId%3D10053%26cm_sp%3DBlackFriday-_-11_23-_-Hero_C-_-349_Each_GE_Washer_Dryer_Special_Buy%23.UK-DHuOe_VQ

How do I go about extracting the url to the og:image?

Comment: Read the page’s source code, and search for and extract the contents of the meta element with property "og:image" – using string functions, regular expressions or DOM methods. Btw., the page you mentioned does __not__ have this tag set, as the debug tool’s output explicitly says.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe. You're right, in the example I provided, facebook "infers" the image. How do I go about reading a page's source code?  Do you know of any resources I can refer to to implement that feature? I've never done that before.

Comment: _“How do I go about reading a page's source code?”_ – by making an HTTP (GET) request. And yes, I know a wonderful resource – it’s called _Google_ …

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up using [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) like below, while relying heavy on this tutorial by [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/190-screen-scraping-with-nokogiri).

```
def photo_from_url(url)
  if !Nokogiri::HTML(open(url)).css("meta[property='og:image']").blank?
    photo_url = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url)).css("meta[property='og:image']").first.attributes["content"]
    self.photo = URI.parse(photo_url)
    self.save
  end
end
```

I found this to be more reliable than the [opengraph gem](https://github.com/intridea/opengraph):

```
url_with_photo = opengraph.fetch(url)
url_with_photo.image
```

as this second method sometimes doesn't work, even on pages that have an og:image tag in the  source code. (I didn't implement it completely wrong, as it did work on some pages...).

Answer (score 0):

Your pages don´t have any Open Graph tags. See here for a description and examples: http://ogp.me/

Facebook reads those tags when a user shares a link.

The debugger tells you what to do btw:

> Inferred Property: The 'og:url' property should be explicitly
> provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
>
> Inferred Property: The 'og:title' property should be explicitly provided, even
> if a value can be inferred from other tags.
>
> Inferred Property: The 'og:description' property should be explicitly provided, even if a
> value can be inferred from other tags.
>
> Inferred Property: The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can
> be inferred from other tags.

But even without the (very important and useful) tags, i can share your link on facebook and it works fine.

Comment: Thanks @luschn. You're right, the page doesn't have an open tag. My question is how to read the tags, not how to create the tags. (ie., I don't work for home depot, but would be interested in using links from sites like that).

Comment: well, you can only use what´s there. if there are no open graph tags, you can just hope that the scraped info is useful. in the case of your link, it works without any problem for me on facebook. if you don´t own the page and want to use content, always ask the site owner if you are allowed to do this btw.

Comment: Thanks @luschn. Given a page with an og:image, how do I get to it? How do I "scrape" a page given the url? This may be a bit broad, but would appreciate it if you could point me to any tutorials or explanations on the subject, as I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: well > file_get_contents or curl > parse the page and search for the og-tags.

Comment: or if you want to get the data from a specific page:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.devils-heaven.com%2Fheroku-gratis-ssl-fur-facebook-apps%2F

scroll down to "Graph API: https://graph.facebook.com/10150708135007395" > you can make a simple graph api call with that id. but this only works if facebook knows about the page (because of a like button, open graph tags, ...)

Comment: Thanks @luschn. I think I found my answer in this [railscast on nokogiri](http://railscasts.com/episodes/190-screen-scraping-with-nokogiri)

Answer (score 0):

If you know the ID of the page, you can append /picture to the end of the Graph API URL to get redirected to the image associated with it, whether explicit or implicit.

For example, one of the commenters below mentions ID 10150708135007395 (http://www.devils-heaven.com/heroku-gratis-ssl-fur-facebook-apps/), so to get the thumbnail image, simply grab:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/10150708135007395/picture
```

Answer (score 0):

```
module MetaParser

  require 'open-uri'

  COMMON_USER_AGENTS = ['Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36','Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36','Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0','Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36']  

  def self.parse_doc(url)
    Nokogiri::HTML.parse(open(url,'User-Agent' => COMMON_USER_AGENTS.sample ))  
  end   

  module Facebook
    def self.get_attributes(url)
      attributes = {}
      doc = MetaParser.parse_doc(url)

      attributes[:url]   = url
      attributes[:site_name] = doc.at('meta[property="og:site_name"]')['content']
      attributes[:title] = doc.at('meta[property="og:title"]')['content'] 
      attributes[:description] = doc.at('meta[property="og:description"]')['content']
      attributes[:image] = doc.at('meta[property="og:image"]')['content']

      return attributes
    end
  end # Facebook  

  module Twitter
    def self.get_attributes(url)
      attributes = {}
      doc = MetaParser.parse_doc(url)

      attributes[:url]   = url
      attributes[:site_name] = doc.at('meta[name="twitter:site"]')['content']
      attributes[:title] = doc.at('meta[name="twitter:title"]')['content'] 
      attributes[:description] = doc.at('meta[name="twitter:description"]')['content']
      attributes[:image] = doc.at('meta[name="twitter:image"]')['content']

      return attributes
    end  
  end # Twitter     

end
```

Usage:

MetaParser::Facebook.get_attributes("google.com")
MetaParser::Twitter.get_attributes("google.com")